# Как ускорить функцию AnsiLowerCase?

Tags: delphi

Возможно сделать, как то быстрее, работу функции `AnsiLowerCase`:

К примеру код:

```
 if (Pos(AnsiLowerCase('Zapros'), AnsiLowerCase(s)) > 0) then
  writeln(f, S);
```

Работает в три раза медленней нежели без этой функции:

```
if (Pos('Zapros', s) > 0) then
  writeln(f, S);
```

Кто может посоветовать?

Comment: Татьяна, как замеряли скорость выполнения кода?

Comment: @Dima, ну просто через opendialog открыла файл и обработала его в двух вариантах кода. И получается что? с учетом регистра, то есть без функции AnsiLowerCase - работает намного быстрее.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1554544/1216425 немного на тему

Comment: попробуйте проведите тест с `TStopWatch` , хоть цифры какие то будут

Comment: замечу, что приведение `AnsiLowerCase('Zapros')` можно опустить, или вынести за пределы цикла обработки

Comment: @teran, Я так поняла, с ссылки, что функцию Pos можно заменить на функцию не чувствительную к регистру ?

Comment: Татьяна, я имею в виду следующее: имеются ли у Вас *зафиксированное* время выполнения кода, представленного в двух различных вариантах? Что-то вроде 1:23 (вариант А) и 3:47 (Вариант Б) соответственно. Если нет, то *как* Вы определили разницу в скорости выполнения кода?

Comment: @Dima, Да имеется. С функцией файл в 10 мегабайт обрабатывается 3 минуты. А без функции 1 минута и 15 секунд.

Comment: @teran, Спасибо Вам: Все получилось, работает отлично! - использовала функцию по той ссылке что Вы предоставили! Также благодарна:  Dima и Kromster.

Comment: @teran, Оформите ответ что бы я могла пометить его как ответ, просто, также оставьте ссылку, в ответ и все. Все таки, по справедливости, я же использовала ваш совет.  Потому ожидаю, после чего отмечу как ответ...

Comment: да лучше вы сами :) я честно сказать там даже не читал что в посте том написано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если данные и алгоритм позволяют, то приведите весь обрабатываемый текст и все ключевые слова (например, 'Zapros') к нижнему регистру **один раз при старте** алгоритма.

Comment: Про ключевые слова - здоровая идея; про весь текст - не совсем. Если объем текста будет весьма велик, то придется расходовать процессорное время на преобразование регистра текста впустую.

Comment: @Dima зависит от объема и соотношения рабочих данных ко всем данным. Нам ни то ни другое не известно. Так что общее решение - попрофилировать.

Comment: В любом случае, изменять регистр *всего* текста только лишь с целью облегчения поиска ключевых слов - это плохая идея.

Comment: @Dima опять же, не владея полнотой задачи, этого утверждать нельзя. Например у меня идет парсинг данных в которых ключевых слов 5%, а остальное регистро-независимые данные и цифры. В таком случае способ отлично помогает.

Comment: Ладно, уговорили. Видимо, для совсем малого объема текста можно так поступить. Хотя лично я бы не стал. В общем, ждем расширения вопроса путем добавления необходимых данных.

Comment: @Dima, Использовала функцию из этой темы и все заработало!: stackoverflow.com/a/1554544/1216425

Comment: @Татьяна, рад за Вас! Теперь остается подождать, пока пользователь teran оформит свой ответ и Вы сможете принять его. Либо придется (в крайнем случае) принять ответ пользователя Kromster.